# ¿ Se puede afectar a un elemento que este en el mismo contenedor?

Tags: html, css

Bueno pues estoy en un proyecto sera mejor que veáis el código , creo que css3 no lo permite el afectar con algún selector a un elemento que este antes de el elento principal, Si lo ejecutáis veréis que el css no afecta al elemento Primero para que haga pequeño, y se bugea y el Segundo elemento se pone abajo porque supera el 100%

```css
/* COLORES: #128C4E  #8C261A #024027 #401309*/


.Proyectos ul li.ProyectoNormal {
  background: #128C4E;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 4%;
  margin: 1%;
}
.Proyectos ul li.ProyectoGrande {
  background: #128C4E;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 4%;
  margin: 1%;
}
.Proyectos ul li {
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  float:left;
}
.Proyectos ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
}






.Proyectos ul li.Primero:hover {
  animation-name: Primero;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.Proyectos ul li.Segundo:hover {
  animation-name: Segundo;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes Primero {
    0% { height: 40px; width: 40%;}
    50% { height: 150px; width: 50%;}
    100% { height: 200px; width: 60%;}
}
@keyframes Segundo {
    0% {float: right; height: 40px; width: 40%;}
    50% {float: right; height: 150px; width: 50%;}
    100% {float: right; height: 200px; width: 60%;}
}







.Proyectos ul li.Primero:hover ~ .Segundo{
  animation-name: Pequeño;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.Proyectos ul li.Segundo:hover ~ .Primero{
  animation-name: Pequeño;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes Pequeño {
    0% { height: 40px; width: 40%;}
    50% { height: 150px; width: 30%;}
    100% { height: 200px; width: 20%;}
}






.Proyectos ul li.ProyectoGrande:hover {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  animation-name: Grande;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes Grande {
    0% { height: 40px; }
    50% { height: 150px; }
    100% { height: 200px; }
}
```

```html
      <div class="Proyectos">
        <ul>
            <li class="ProyectoNormal Primero"><a href="">

                <h2>Proyecto 1</h2>

            </a></li>
            <li class="ProyectoNormal Segundo"><a href="">

                <h2>Proyecto 2</h2>

            </a></li>

          <li class="ProyectoGrande"><a href="">

              <h2>Proyecto 3</h2>

          </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con el selector `nth-child()`? Aquí un ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: ¿Qué Es exactamente lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que la animación que ocurre con el primer recuadro al hacer hover también ocurra al hacer hover en el 2º

Comment: nth-child(x) no sirve, al menos como yo lo intento pero muchas gracias

Comment: Podrías hacerlo menos elegante con una clase para ese elemento específico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes ir "hacia atrás" en la jerarquía del DOM con CSS, todo lo mas afectar a elementos al mismo nivel, y solo si están detrás del elemento, es decir, puedes hacer:

```
.primero:hover ~ .segundo{
```

Pero no puedes afectar a .primero desde .segundo usando solo CSS, tienes que usar JS